# Webpack: for some modules, leave the 'require' statement as is

Tags: webpack

Goal:  For some libraries matching a pattern P, have `webpack` emit / compile the `require` statement as is.

Example:

1. Suppose I have a `mylib` that I want to got through `as-is`, so that require works at run-time.
2. and code like this.

`var b = require("./some.stuff.that.webpack.should.inline");
    a = require('mylib/should/stay/a/Require');`

I want output that looks like this

```
  /******/ ([
  /* 0 */
  /***/ function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

          a = __webpack_require__(1);


  /***/ },
  /* 1 */
  /***/ function(module, exports) {

          module.exports = require('mylib/should/stay/a/Require');
```

I know a Plugin can do this, but I am having trouble intercepting the right event/ understanding [the plugin docs](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/how-to-write-a-plugin)

Tried so far:
1.  `external`... this assumes definition is somewhere else
2.  `IgnorePlugin` gives a `webpackMissingModule` ... the opposite of what I want.

Answer (score 1):

With your first attempt you probably was referring to https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/, so most likely you were very close to come up with a solution.

To be honest using `externals` might be bit unintuitive, as it is not fully documented and it requires to specify the loading mechanism as a part of a string (instead of proper js object).

To instruct webpack to leave some `require` as-is, please use something like that in your config file (tested with *v4.25.5*):

```
const IGNORED = ['dep1', 'dep2']

module.exports = {
  // ...
  // other options
  // ...
  externals: IGNORED.reduce((acc, p) => (acc[p] = `commonjs ${p}`, acc), {})
};
```

If you need a bit more flexibility use the `function` approach:

```
 externals: (_, req, cb) => {
    if (IGNORED.indexOf(req) >= 0) {
      return cb(null, `commonjs ${req}`)
    }
    cb()
  }
```

If you omit `commonjs` global scope will be used to resolve the dependency.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone like me comes across this and is looking for a webpack 5 solution, you can do it like this:

```js
module.exports = {
  // other options
  externals: [
    'some_lib',
    'some_other_lib'
  ],
  externalsType: 'commonjs',
}
```

Externals can also be a regex or a function, the full set of options is listed in [webpack's externals documentation](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/)